# Should you put an "a" before some words?

Tags: articles, zero-article

I read this on a website:

> *A skilled customer service provider must develop abilities to effectively assess **a** situation, establish rapport, defuse anger, and work with wide diversity of customer cultural backgrounds.*

I wonder why there is an article *a* before the word *situation* but not also before *rapport*, *anger* or *work*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a trickier idea than you'd think.

'Situation' is always a countable noun, meaning it's a thing you could count on your fingers. So you can have 'a situation', 'two situations', 'some situations', or 'many situations'. But you can't have 'some situation'.

'Rapport' and 'anger' are like 'peace' - they aren't countable.

You can use them as singular nouns ('we formed a peace between our nations', or 'we have a rapport'), but you can't make them plural. You can't have 'some peaces' or 'some rapports'.

Instead of having a plural, those words can be used as conditions, much like the word 'dryness' ('there is peace between our nations' or 'we have rapport'). You can also have 'some anger', or 'some rapport'.

'Rapport' is usually a singular noun. So 'establish a rapport' is more common than 'establish rapport'. 'Anger' is usually a condition. So you can 'have anger', but you don't usually 'have an anger'.

I would write your sentence as:

> A skilled customer service provider must develop abilities to effectively assess a situation, establish a rapport, defuse anger, and work with a wide variety of customer cultural backgrounds.

Comment: *Defuse* is definitely the right word here. You're not trying to spread out the anger, you're trying to deescalate and calm the person down. Also, *establish/build rapport* is a common no-article phrase in that area.

Comment: "But you can't have 'some situation'." While I agree that in this case, 'some situation' is not correct, you could have a sentence like: "Don't call me after 10pm unless there's some situation I need to address." Perhaps "a situation" would be better, and I'm not sure if "some situation" is actually *technically* correct, but it does see usage in spoken English, at the very least. I'm guessing that in this case "some" isn't referring to amount, so it's different.

Comment: @imkingdavid - yes, you're absolutely right. In your sentence `Don't call me after 10pm unless there's some situation I need to address.`, `some situation` winds up meaning "one situation of an unknown type", and is perfectly OK!